# An estimator for the amount of change in a time series

Tags: time-series, variance, variability, dispersion

I have data like this:

```
      Bond Cash Stock
Day1    65  66  50
Day2    10  69  75
Day3    35  75  69
Day4    34  96  95
Day5    25  63  40
Day6    5   6   92
Day7    16  77  27
Day8    11  58  35
Day9    84  0   30
Day10   14  12  55
Day11   86  84  80
Day12   11  90  35
```

I am looking for an estimator for the amount of change in the portfolio (the values are money) from day to day. I don't think that looking at the variance of the portfolio in the right way - because "11 60 5" and "5 11 60" has the same variance. Any suggestion?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Consider variance of *changes* rather than *levels*. After all, you are interested in changes.

- *Levels* of `11 60 5` will result in *changes* of `49 -55` and variance of 5408,

while

- *levels* of `5 11 60` will result in *changes* of `6 49` and a variance of 924.5.

So you get an intuitive result when you consider variance of *changes*.

Comment: So you think I should calculate the diffrences between "bond" , "cash"  and "stock" in each day and calculate the variance on them?

Comment: Whatever is the time series of interest, I suggest calculating the variance of changes rather than levels. If you care about `bond`, do that for `bond`. If you care about portfolio, obtain one series for the portfolio and obtain the variance of the changes in that series.